# CodeIgniter cannot load database library manually or autoload; Call to Member function get() on a non object

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-2

I'm unable to load the database library correctly manually in my model or in autoload.php

The line *$query = $this->db->get('videos');* produces a **Call to Member function get() on a non object error** indicating the database library is not loaded.

I try loading the database library using the two lines commented out in the constructor for the model below but both return errors. If I uncomment $this->load->database I get a *Call to member function **database()** on a non object* error,

If I uncomment $this->load->library('database') I get a *Call to member function **library()** on a non object error*

```
<?php 
class Videos_model extends CI_Model {
  public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->database();
        //$this->load->library('database');
    }

    public function get_videos() 
    {
           $query = $this->db->get('videos');
    }

}
```

The same line **$this->load->database();** in the controller does not produce an error but the get() function error.

```
class Videos extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('url'));
            $this->load->database();
             //$this->load->library('database');
            $this->load->model('videos_model');
            $this->videos_model->get_videos();           
    }
}
```

I also have set autoload in the config file,

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

in my CI Log file database driver is indicated to be initialized
    DEBUG - 2013-05-09 15:31:17 --> Database Driver Class Initialized

Here is my database config as well,

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'dbusername';
$db['default']['password'] = 'dbpassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I'm using CI 2.1.3 in eclipse with aptana studio 3 plugin and phpMyAdmin 3.5.8.1 and Apache Server 2.2

Update:
I've confirmed that accessing the database works from the controller but not the model.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your database config. The only thing that I can see is that you're referring to your model in all lower case in your controller. The CI documentation states that model classes should start with a capital letter and that they should also be referenced that way, too. ($this->load->model('Videos_model') / $this->Videos_model->get_videos();). Whether this will make a difference or not, I do not know.

Comment: @MichaelO'Brien its seems to be working with the lowercase reference but I changed it to be more in line with conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I had used this tutorial to get autocompletion working in Eclipse, http://www.taggedzi.com/articles/display/autocomplete-eclipse-codeigniter-2, (link 404'd)
Once I removed the extra code in controller.php and model.php database access in the model was restored.

Here is a better tutorial on how to get autocomplete working in eclipse, http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-and-eclipse-autocomplete/ (read the comments to find out how to get it working in models as well as controllers).

Comment: the first link is 404. I'll try the second link.